# RewriteConditions to stop processing catch all htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out the correct rules and condition such that a catch all rewrite rule is not matched following the successful match of a different rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^dev/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ ApplicationPublic/APP/index_dev.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index_dev.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ApplicationPublic/APP/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Unfortunately, the rules continue to process, and the last catch all is used to match.

How do I structure the rules and conditions so that it stops processing at `/dev/Param1/Param2` ?

Comment: If it is Apache 2.4+, use `END` flag

Comment: @hjpotter92 I'm using Apache 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^dev/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ ApplicationPublic/APP/index_dev.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index_dev\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ApplicationPublic/APP/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

...to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The `[OR]` is allowing one or the other condition to be disregarded. A directory is not a file, so it passes. And a file is not a directory, so it too passes.

Here you want to pass the condition where the `REQUEST_FILENAME` is not a file AND is not a directory.